# Adobe Air 23 + iOS 10.1.1 full screen

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-builder, starling-framework, feathers-ui

I am using `Air` latest version with `Starling` and `feathers` latest versions.

My problem is how my application is not getting full height on iPhone 6 latest iOS (version 10.1.1) I am also using launch images and they are working correctly on the device. See [iPhone screen photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrBDD.png).

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: If you have a working solution then mark it as correct using the `✓` tick symbol. It helps others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best practice i know is using a parent container instead stage, a root child of stage which would be parent of everything

for example `root_container`

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
root_container.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
root_container.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

**Note**: if your app is responsible to orientation changes, you have to handle them as your wish